# Backing Up Forwarded Events

Tags: powershell, automation, windows-event-log

I have created a simple test two liner ps script to backup parts of my event logs and the only one I can't backup is the forwarded events, is there a reason for this? The other logs back up fine with the same script when I change the name. The error I am getting is: `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression`. Also when I try to read the size of the file and get its max, it also throws a fit. Thinking for some reason things are not mapped the same but not sure where to look.

```
$EventLog = Get-WmiObject Win32_NTEventlogFile -Filter "LogFileName = 'ForwardedEvents'"

$EventLog.BackupEventlog("F:\AF\Test.evt")
```

Comment: The Win32_NTEventLogFile WMI class is ancient. It may need to be configured to use non-legacy event logs.  See: https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/guide/add-event-log-files-to-the-win32-ntlogevent-wmi-class/

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of digging on the web as well as in the registry, I found that the Forwarded Events are more of a channel and can be managed through Get-WinEvent class. Think I will go this route as I am concerned about breaking what is already touchy(Windows Event Collector)

Do appreciate your thoughts but found a few post that were negative after creating a workaround as that site demonstrated.

The answer was here on ServerFault all along: [Good example of WinEvent Class and backups](https://serverfault.com/questions/843645/need-a-backup-of-entire-event-log-of-windows-servers-using-cmd-or-powershell)